# Keep Checking: Angular Observable from Promise

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-promise

I am developing an angular app which connects to the printer. The printer has its own status service which is a promise and it responds with printer status. In my angular app, I need a functionality where I need to keep checking status of the printer in the background. For this I am trying to use observable and subscribe function which is not working as expected.

In my **PrinterService.ts** component, I have defined the function as:

```
getStatus() {
  return from(cordova.xyz.getPrinterStatus()); // getPrinterStatus() is a promise
}
```

And I am consuming this function in my **HomePage.ts** as:

```
this.printerService.getStatus().subscribe( (res) => {
  console.log("Printer Status", res);
}
```

The problem here is I am getting the status response but just once. For example, if my printer is on, it will give me "on" status but it just prints inside console as once. But when after 2-3 minutes, if I switch off the printer, it should give me status as "off". How do I make this work in such as way that my getStatus() services automatically looks for printer status? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to poll as a promise only resolves a single time, use a timer

```js
const { timer, of } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, distinctUntilChanged } = rxjs.operators;

const printerService = {
  getStatus: () => of((Math.random() < .5) ? 'off' : 'on')
}

timer(0, 500).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => printerService.getStatus()),
  distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe(res => {
  console.log("Printer Status", res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

distinctUntilChanged will mean the observable only emits when the status changes rather than every time it polls.

```js
const { timer, of } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, scan, distinctUntilChanged } = rxjs.operators;

const printerService = {
  getStatus: () => of({ status: (Math.random() < .5) ? 'off' : 'on' })
}

timer(0, 500).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => printerService.getStatus()),
  scan((previous, current) => current.status === previous.status ? previous : current),
  distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe(res => {
  console.log("Printer Status", res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

You can use scan to emit the previous object if it has the same status, this means distinctUntilChanged gets the same object so you are only emitting on status change.

Comment: will distinctUntilChanged() works if my getStatus() resolved to a json object in case of on status and rejects to an error string in case of off ststus?

Comment: No, if it is a reference object but if you put a map in there to make it a value object such as a string on or off it will work. If you need the emitted value to be an object you could use a scan .

Comment: The problem here is my code does not identify current.status and previous.status inside scan() method. My getStatus() method:

1. Resolves to an object { connection: 1, coverOpen: 0, errorStatus: 0, isPrintable: true, online: 1, paper: 0, paperFeed: 0} if the printer is connected.
2. Rejects to string "Error 0x00013: Printer is not connected" if my printer is not connected. 

I tried using previous.online and current.online but scan() gives me error "Property 'online' does not exist on type 'unknown'."

Comment: scan is like a reduce function, I am reducing the stream to either a new value or the previous value. You need to add a map function in before the scan that transforms the getStatus result into what is object you need for this situation. If your map function returns a string 'online' or 'offline' you wont even need a scan as you have a value object that will get filtered by distinctUntilChanged

Comment: That worked. One more question: Do you know how can I cancel that subscription if I don't receive any response at all from getStatus() ???